# Windows Server 2008 - Find out who put a user to a local user group?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

How it´s possible to find out, who put a user on a WS 2008 R2 server to a local group?

Sometimes I´m wondering, why is this user on this system in this group.
I think, the easiest way is to ask the guy who did it :-)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: IT should have a change control policy and ticketing system that documents all changes and why.  Easier said than done, but works.

Answer (score 3):

You can audit account creation, change, deletion, etc. with the native auditing capabilities of Windows Server systems.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737542%28v=ws.10%29.aspx